# Java Regex validation

Tags: java, regex

I maybe miss something, but i'd like to know why this pattern is valid :

```
Pattern.compile("([0-9]{1,})");
```

The compile does not throw an exception despite that the occurence is not valid.

Thx a lot

Comment: Why do you think it is not valid?

Comment: It is valid `{x,}` means at least `x` times and `{,x}` means at most `x` times.

Comment: @maraca "{x,} means at least x times" is true, but "{,x} means at most x times" is false since `{,x}` is not proper regex (at least in Java), we need explicit `{0,x}` for such case.

Comment: @Pshemo you are correct: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/quant.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> despite that the occurence is not valid

quantifiers can be represented using `{n,m}` syntax where:

- `{n}` - exactly `n` times
- `{n,}` - at least `n` times
- `{n,m}` - at least `n` but not more than `m` times

Source: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/quant.html

(notice that there is no `{,m}` quantifier representing "not more than `m` times") because we don't really need one, we can create it via `{0,m}`)

So `{1,}` **is valid** and simply means "at least once".
To avoid confusion we can simplify it by replacing `{1,}` quantifier with more known form `+` like

```
Pattern.compile("([0-9]+)");
```

Most probably you also don't need to create capturing group 1 by surrounding `[0-9]+` with parenthesis. We can access what regex matched with help of group 0, so such group 1 is redundant in most cases.

Comment: The `()` is also superfluous if everything is captured then match0 equals match1.

Comment: @maraca True, will add to answer.